# Migrating /home to new hard drive after old one died, root on separate drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have my Ubuntu installation setup such that my OS is on an internal SSD and `/home` and my `/swap` partition were on a separate internal HDD, both on my laptop.

That HDD started breaking so I replaced it, but I am unsure of how to go about partitioning my new hard drive, editing fstab and so on in order to revert my laptop to its previous state.
Also my previous `/home` directory was encrypted, though I can easily do that later.

Any help or links to previous questions would be greatly appreciated.
I am using (or was) Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You need larger disk with enough space to hold the image for this operation but it will save you time and other problems:

1. connect old hdd and mount it in read only mode, then `cat` the old failing disk onto a bigger disk (normally you would do that with `dd` but `cat` also works and is way faster). The image will serve as a backup. You can do that with:

```
cat /dev/sda > /home/user/failing_hard_disk.image
```

(I assume /dev/sda is your failing hard drive in this case, but it will be definitely different letter at the end if it's not main drive anymore)

2. Connect the new HDD
3. cat the image back onto the new connected drive:

```
cat /home/user/failing_hard_disk.image > /dev/sdd
```

(I assume /dev/sdd is the new drive you have connected, this operation will override EVERYTHING you have on new disk, so if you have precious data there, copy them somewhere else before running this)

4. use gparted to resize the remaining space on /dev/sdd (in casse partition sizes do not match the new disk)
5. disconnect failed drive (you can also disconnect it right after making the image, doesn't matter, we stopped using ti right after the image was made)
6. reboot and change bios to boot from new disk

You computer will now behave EXACTLY as it did before (same disk contents), well except it will not fail anywhere soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You say to change the bios to boot from the new disk, however I shouldn't have to do that, since my os is installed on an SSD also on my laptop. Also could I just cat the old HDD onto my new HDD if I can connect them at the same time? Also surely I need to change something in fstab?

Comment: If you have other disks conencted you may have to change it, but maybe it's not necessary. i.e on desktops it may be if you connected it with different SATA port, but on laptops this should ususally work without the BIOS changes. 
`cat`ing one drive to the other is possible, but none of those drives should be currently used (so to do that, system should be booted from third drive e.g:usb stick)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer from janmyszkier, but unfortunately `cat`ing wasn't possible (probably because my old hdd a bad sector), so what I ended up doing was:

1. Boot up ubuntu from a Live CD / USB and chose ''Try Ubuntu''
2. Formatted the old HDD to the same settings as the old one (i.e. ext4)
3. Found out which HDD was which using `fdisk -l` (or gparted, which I also used to format the old HDD)
4. Mount the two HDDs (the new one having been installed on my laptop, the old one connected by USB using a 2.5'' external sata case) by doing something like:

   sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/old_hdd # Note that the directory where you're mounting must exist
5. Used `rsync` to copy over the files

   rsync -av --delete --info=progress2 /mnt/old_hdd/ /mnt/hdd
6. Read a book for a bit
7. Changed the UUIDs in fstab to point to the right partitions for `/swap` and `/home`
8. Booted up and everything worked fine.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: On a side note, I would not recommend to keep entire home on HDD. Your desktop needs lots of hidden files under ~/.config, ~/.local etc. These should come from SDD. To achieve this, have /home on SDD but symlink ~/Documents, ~/Music, ~/Videos, ~/Downloads to their counterparts on HDD.